# Why when i try to scrap a site to get the poucentage number the value is always 0?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.10

I want to extract the pourcentage value with beautifulsoup. I tried to get all  value on the page but it returns always 0%.

I want to scrap this value:

[image]

On [this](https://www.horoscope.fr/horoscopes/aujourdhui/scorpion) web site.

Here is my code to get all the pourcentage value :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://www.horoscope.fr/horoscopes/aujourdhui/scorpion"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")

trucs = soup.find_all('strong')

for truc in trucs:
    print(truc.text)
```

And i get this :

```
0%
0%
0%
0%
0%
0%
15 € les 10 minutes
Gui
Apple cobbler
```

How can i extract the value ?

Comment: How do you expect to apply a technical solution to a magical problem?

Comment: The website has javascript rendering. You can use selenium to render javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joking aside, here is one way of obtaining horoscope values (you can eventually map them to a percentage for a 1-6 scale):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import json

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.horoscope.fr/horoscopes/aujourdhui/scorpion'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('script[id="__NEXT_DATA__"]').text)
magic_stuffs = data['props']['pageProps']['initialProps']['horoscope']['overviews']
df = pd.json_normalize(magic_stuffs)
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
rating  title   iconUrl titleColor  anchorId
0   5   AMOUR   https://cdn.tlmq.fr/mbe/horoscope/rating_5_v1.png   #000    love
1   2   TRAVAIL https://cdn.tlmq.fr/mbe/horoscope/rating_2_v1.png   #000    career
2   4   BIEN-ÊTRE   https://cdn.tlmq.fr/mbe/horoscope/rating_4_v1.png   #000    wellbeing
3   5   VIE SOCIALE https://cdn.tlmq.fr/mbe/horoscope/rating_5_v1.png   #000    social_life
4   4   AMBIANCE    https://cdn.tlmq.fr/mbe/horoscope/rating_4_v1.png   #000    mood
5   2   FINANCES    https://cdn.tlmq.fr/mbe/horoscope/rating_2_v1.png   #000    finances
```

You can map the integer values to displayed percentages (a 5 rating is an 83%, 2 is 33%, and so on).

Those percentages are displayed dynamically by javascript executed in page, so Requests cannot see them, and bs4 cannot parse them.

Relevant documentation for Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

And for BeautifulSoup: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/